# Save state at each breakpoint with visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

first of all, I'm sorry if this question will result stupid. I'm new with C# and Visual Studio, and I can't find a feature I was used to with IntelliJ Community and Java.

[image: IntelliJ let me see the values of all the variables at each breakpoint]

With IntelliJ, when I setted a breakpoint for debugging a cycle, I could have seen all the values of all the variables at each breakpoint. With the "local variables" window, in Visual Studio, I can see only the values at the latest breakpoint. Is there any similar feature?

Thank you.

Comment: A hit to a breakpoint represents a point in time, I'm not sure I understand what it means to see the value in other breakpoints, but when you hit a breakpoint you can see the the current thread's local variables in the Locals window. You can switch threads in the Threads window and use the Watch window to view other variables, like static members, etc. What are you missing?

Comment: @ZivS thank you for your response. Suppose to add a breakpoint inside a for cycle. In IntelliJ, I was able to access the values of all the variables for each breakpoint is reached. So I was able to see how the variables varied at each execution of the cycle. In C#, instead, I'm just able to see the value of all the variables at the latest execution of the breakpoint.

Comment: Sounds like something that would be nice to have: A history snapshot of all states of all or all participating variables. Something like a snapshot-breakpoint, right? I doubt we have it in VS; not sure about add-ins..

Comment: @TaW exactly. It's strange this feature isn't available in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible in Visual Studio.

However it shouldn't be hard "emulating" that feature using the `Output` window, using `Tracepoints`:

Right click a breakpoint -> Choose `Actions...` -> Then check the `Actions` checkbox and add a message for the output window (you can choose to break if you clear the `Continue Execution` checkbox, or have it stop like a normal breakpoint).

In the message, you can add the name of any variable within curly braces. To get the same information as in your screenshot, you could use something like:

```
it.polimi.bobema = [{it.polimi.bobema}]
```

Now debug your application and you should see that data in the `Output` window in Visual Studio.

You can use some special variables in the tracepoint message, like `$ADDRESS`, `$CALLER`, `$CALLSTACK`, `$FUNCTION`, etc. You can find more (and more information about break/tracepoints) at [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx)

Some screenshots:

[image: Tracepoint settings]

Yields result (in the output window):

[image: Output window]

Comment: Thank you man, this is very useful! Do you think I can print a 2-D matrix too?

Comment: You can print whatever, however this is meant for temporary simple traces. If you want to print something more "complicated", I recommend `Debug.Write` or `Trace.Write` and/or conditional debug methods

Answer (score -2):

In Visual Studio after open your project go to **Debug Menu** => **Windows** =>  **Breakpoints**